# Find a process id using netstat in combination with ps

Tags: linux, bash

I want to find the process id using netstat and see how long this process has been running by using ps.  I currently have two separate commands to do this.  How do I do it with one command?

```
netstat -anp | grep http | grep ESTABLISHED | awk {'print $7}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'}
```

and:

```
ps -eo pid,uid,ruser,etime | grep someuser
```

Answer (score 14):

```
for i in `netstat -anp | grep http | grep ESTABLISHED | awk {'print $7}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'} | uniq` ; do ps -eo pid,uid,ruser,etime | grep $i ; done
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Should have thought of that.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please be kind and accept it.

Comment: instead of `uniq` I'd prefer `sort -u` to avoid duplicates in the pid list

Comment: Seems like one of the single quotes in `{'print $7}'` may be misplaced (though the command seems to work anyway).